# ajax jquery support in spring mvc

Tags: jquery

i am new to both jquery and ajax... i want to use these technologies in my current spring mvc project.... what all do i need???? is spring json required in this scenario?? is spring json or jquery any way similar to each other?? if required is there any sample tutorial where in spring json is used alongwith ajax jquery in order to get a complete hang of it.,.. Any help is thanked in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [Spring MVC-Ajax](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) sample app is a good start, it uses JQuery `$.getJSON` to get a JSON from the Server.

Comment: The MVC-AJAX example is a bit hard to understand.... Is there any other example???? easy to understand....

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a good example with sample code and explanation:

[Spring 3 MVC + AJAX + jQuery](http://maxheapsize.com/2010/07/20/spring-3-mvc-ajax-and-jquery-magic-or-better-simplicity/)

Answer (score 0):

Well I just wrote this approach up, because I was tired of not having control over the serialization and deserialization of the JSON, I agree its a little heavy, but when you are finished with it you have 100% control over the marshaling. It falls back on ObjectMapper so if you choose not to use a template it works too.

http://technotantor.blogspot.com/2011/10/jquery-and-spring.html